# Unexpected size increase of MySql table after CREATE table LIKE and INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, sql-insert, create-table

I am trying to copy a table in mysql (version 5.7.38-1) using the following queries:

```
CREATE TABLE dest LIKE src;
INSERT INTO dest SELECT * FROM src;
```

Table dest is created and filled with records from Table src. So far, so good. You would expect the two tables to have roughly the same size. But Table dest has 646M, whereas Table src only has 134M. After the create-step, Table dest is 48K, more or less as expected.

Engine is InnoDB, default row format is dynamic and compression is on.

I have executed the following to see if it would help but to no avail:

```
ALTER TABLE dest ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
OPTIMIZE TABLE dest;
```

And this is `SHOW CREATE TABLE src`:

```
CREATE TABLE `src` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6046271 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I am aware that the mysql version is dated but changing that is outside my scope of control.

Two questions:

1. What is the reason for this unexpected behavior?
2. What is the solution to make Table dest smaller?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: How did you measure the table size? Numbers from information_schema are very approximate estimates.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: I originally took the table sizes from the Database Navigator in DBeaver, but taking them from the information_schema yields the same sizes. Size of Table desc is 5x that of Table src - that may be an approximation, but it seems very unlikely that the two tables are in fact the same sizes.

Comment: This is the WordPress `wp_postmeta` table. Just sayin'  And, a guess: did the big INSERT INTO operation allocate a clustered index (the chunk of the tablespace where the data goes) with a relatively low fill percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Various possibilities.  The most likely is the indexes.

What engine?  Was compression on?  What row format?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE src`.

`INSERT ... SELECT ...` will feed the rows into the table one at a time (but a lot faster than one `INSERT` statement per row).  If the Engine is `InnoDB`, then presumably the `src` rows are in `PRIMARY KEY` order.  And the optimal order for inserting to `dst` is also that order.  So I would expect the data's BTree to be effectively 'defragmented'.

Secondary indexes are another matter.  They may or may not be efficiently ordered.  And the "change buffer" may or may not compensate for the ordering.  The resulting BTree for each secondary index may or may not be 'defragmented'.

What version of mysql/mariadb?  I may have a tool to look deeper into the issue.

Comment: the question was edited to include the additional information you were asking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hmmm... nothing obvious.  What is the typical size of `meta_value`?  (Big columns are stored off record.)  Oh, can you find out the `ROW_FORMAT` of `src` and of `dst`?

Comment: Originally, ROW_FORMAT of both tables was Dynamic. I set it to Compressed for Table dest but that only made a tiny dent in the size. The sizes I mentioned earlier are after ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED for Table dest.

Comment: I've run out of ideas to explain 5x expansion.  (I am not impressed with COMPRESSED; it also has performance drawbacks.)